# Oracle not a group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, analytics

I have a scenario  where I am using a group by, count and a having clause to return some rows, which appears to work fine.

I would like to add another column but I'm running into the problem 'not a group by cause'.

Can someone please provide a solution so I can get my expected results.

Below is my test case

```
CREATE table table_z(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
val NUMBER, 
hash_val VARCHAR2(1000), 
clob_val CLOB);


INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    1,    '4714870AFF6C97CA09D135834FDB58A6389A50C11FEF8EC4AFEF466FB60A23AC6B7A9C92658F14DF4993D6B40A4E4D8424196AFC347E97640D68DE61E1CF14B0',    'aaaaaaaaaa');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    1,    'F368A29B71BD201A7EF78B5DF88B1361FBE83F959756D33793837A5D7B2EAF660F2F6C7E2FBACE01965683C4CFAFDED3FF28AAB34E329AA79BC81E7703F68B86',    'aaaaa');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    2,    '517C1CDB694A83ABF80A1D91EE91059B6443769DBEDDF3F5CC583CCCCC1CCDFE9E5330C61830D9E25AF03536909E8272F056C8FF1FBC9AABD3492C291A735B58',    'Xaaaaaaaaa');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    2,    'D597AD764E82E38DED6184527197C5CA39743F805F1D2355A89E62ECA275D62CD545DDFA57A36B37C711527A63717A69586CBE78AD056A92A0C6479391FC2349',    'xxxx');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    3,    '9B71D224BD62F3785D96D46AD3EA3D73319BFBC2890CAADAE2DFF72519673CA72323C3D99BA5C11D7C7ACC6E14B8C5DA0C4663475C2E5C3ADEF46F73BCDEC043',     'hello');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    1,    '4714870AFF6C97CA09D135834FDB58A6389A50C11FEF8EC4AFEF466FB60A23AC6B7A9C92658F14DF4993D6B40A4E4D8424196AFC347E97640D68DE61E1CF14B0',    'aaaaaaaaaa');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    2,    '4714870AFF6C97CA09D135834FDB58A6389A50C11FEF8EC4AFEF466FB60A23AC6B7A9C92658F14DF4993D6B40A4E4D8424196AFC347E97640D68DE61E1CF14B0',    'aaaaaaaaaa');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    2,    '6522DA2F3FE4F163D52ACEF62440C086BE5EC1203C2CE90A5427546A1CAFE6440618FD3AF2C8A3362AB7BC7544600CA77BED41F95D8038A8A7CC458177691474',    'oracle');

INSERT into table_z (    VAL,    HASH_VAL,    CLOB_VAL) VALUES (
    3,    '6522DA2F3FE4F163D52ACEF62440C086BE5EC1203C2CE90A5427546A1CAFE6440618FD3AF2C8A3362AB7BC7544600CA77BED41F95D8038A8A7CC458177691474',    'oracle');

SELECT hash_val, COUNT(hash_val)
FROM table_z
GROUP BY hash_val
HAVING COUNT(hash_val) > 1;

Current output 
HASH_VAL    COUNT(HASH_VAL)

4714870AFF6C97CA09D135834FDB58A6389A50C11FEF8EC4AFEF466FB60A23AC6B7A9C92658F14DF4993D6B40A4E4D8424196AFC347E97640D68DE61E1CF14B0    3

6522DA2F3FE4F163D52ACEF62440C086BE5EC1203C2CE90A5427546A1CAFE6440618FD3AF2C8A3362AB7BC7544600CA77BED41F95D8038A8A7CC458177691474    2


Desired output. Note the comma delimited seq_num before the hash_val

 SEQ_NUM HASH_VAL COUNT(HASH_VAL)

1,6,7
4714870AFF6C97CA09D135834FDB58A6389A50C11FEF8EC4AFEF466FB60A23AC6B7A9C92658F14DF4993D6B40A4E4D8424196AFC347E97640D68DE61E1CF14B0    3

8,9 6522DA2F3FE4F163D52ACEF62440C086BE5EC1203C2CE90A5427546A1CAFE6440618FD3AF2C8A3362AB7BC7544600CA77BED41F95D8038A8A7CC458177691474    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg` if you are using Oracle 11g R2 or greater.

```
SELECT 
listagg(seq_num,',') within group(order by seq_num) seq_num,
hash_val, COUNT(hash_val)
FROM table_z
GROUP BY hash_val
HAVING COUNT(hash_val) > 1;
```